# Invoking a Perl method

Tags: perl

This works:

```
A::B->new();
```

This doesn't:

```
my $m = 'A::B->new';
&{\&{$m}};
```

How can I make it work? The strange syntax does work for regular functions not containing "->".

Comment: You shouldn't use that "strange syntax" to call a regular subroutine by name either... `$f->()` would work if `$f` was a function name, or the older `&$f()`. Do note that both of those are `strict 'refs'` violations though.

Comment: @Hobbs, `&{\&{$f}}` and the more useful `&{\&{$f}}()` aka `(\&$f)->()` aren't strict violations though. In theory, they should be, but no exception is thrown. A little hole is the wall.

Comment: @ikegami sure, but if you're going to bypass the safety, you might as well say you are by writing `no strict 'refs'` in a block :)

Comment: @hobbs, Yeah, for self-documentation reasons if nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want

```
my $pkg = 'A::B';
my $method = 'new';

$pkg->$method;
```

Comment: That's too easy. Darn.

Comment: Bonus question: why doesn't 'A::B'->'new' work? (without the variables)

Comment: Why should it? No reason to, just like there's no reason to support `'print'("abc\n");`.

Comment: You can quote the left-hand thing, (`'A::B'->$method` will work) but the right-hand thing needs to be a scalar or a bare method name. (Fun fact: the RHS can be a CODE ref. Try it out.) This is actually documented (briefly) in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator).

Comment: That's because `${...}` makes a scalar. :)